# Getting item in a nested array mongoldb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to aggregate an object but getting null. Would appreciate help.

here is my sample object

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "sweatshirt",
    "price.usd": 45.99,
    "am": [
      {
        "one": 100
      }
    ],
    qty: 300
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "item": "winter coat",
    "price.usd": 499.99,
    "am": [
      {
        "one": 50
      }
    ],
    qty: 200
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "item": "sun dress",
    "price.usd": 199.99,
    "am": [
      {
        "one": 10
      }
    ],
    qty: 250
  }
]
```

This is my query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $getField: {
          $literal: "am.one"
        }
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

currently I am getting

```
[
  {
    "_id": null
  }
]
```

any help is appreciated.

I want my response to look like

```
{

_id: 1
anotherThin: anotherValue
}
```

Comment: You don't write what output you expect, but is `$group: {_id: "$am.one"}` closer to what you want to start with?

Comment: Yes, I am actually trying to calculate average but need to get the syntax right.

`_id: { $getField: {$literal: "$am.one" } },
                    avgAmount: { $avg: { $getField: {$literal: "$am.one" } } }`

Comment: If I use just "am" I get a response like this `[
      {
        "one": 10
      }
    ]`

Comment: So you want the average of all `am.one` values, regardless of other document fields?  Will `"am"` always be an array with a single object element, or could there be more elements?

Comment: it could be with more elements. It would always be with more elements.

Comment: This is where I am trying it. https://mongoplayground.net/p/snLOqhHiHBW

Comment: Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/spWHkhg7LeJ "mongoplayground.net -->")?  I'm not sure what you want to do if there are multiple objects in `"am"` that have `"one"`.

Comment: `id` is the id and `one` would be averaged.

Comment: Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6CQnbicxMqV)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { // only pass docs that have a numerical "am.one"
    "$match": {
      "am.one": {"$type": "number"}
    }
  },
  { // unwind in case multiple objects in "am"
    "$unwind": "$am"
  },
  { // group by "id" and average "one" values
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$am.id",
      "am1avg": {"$avg": "$am.one"}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L_EvHF9Zph4).